# How to implement the Windows 10 OneNote Menu in Universal Windows Platform app

Tags: xaml, controls, uwp

I would like to implement the **OneNote app menu** in my own **UWP app**. In the closed state, the menu only shows the 'hamburger' button, but when clicked a menu pane slides in from the left.

I have tried to use the **SplitView**, but it doesn't allow me to set the width to 0 when collapsed, always showing a narrow line on the left side. I also considered using the 8.1 **Flyout** control, but that doesn't see to animate the correct way.

So, what's the correct way to implement the OneNote menu behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `SplitView`, but don't mess with the width of its pane.

Instead, set the [DisplayMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.displaymode.aspx) to `Inline` (or `Overlay`) and toggle the [IsPaneOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.ispaneopen.aspx) property.